# Using ConnectToNewObject with chilkat activex

Tags: registry, powerbuilder, chilkat, powerbuilder-build-deploy, createoleobject

I used `Chilkat ActiveX` in my PowerBuilder script

```
loo_Sb = create oleobject
li_rc =loo_Sb.ConnectToNewObject("Chilkat_9_5_0.StringBuilder")
if li_rc < 0 then
    destroy loo_Sb
    MessageBox("Error","Connecting to COM object failed")
    return
end if
```

and it worked correctly.

When I did the deploy and try running my exe on my client pc the ole object, it didn't work and returned error *Connecting to COM object failed*.

What should I install or put in the my client pc to make the `Chilkat` ole object work correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

An ActiveX DLL needs to be registered (regsvr32) on each computer where it is used.  I would highly recommend reading this [tutorial about ActiveX registration](https://chilkatsoft.com/activex_dll_registration_tutorial.asp) -- it's a short read.